# Is it possible to infer generic `T | undefined` as `Partial<T>` without casting?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this function that applies default values to an object if it's undefined. For properties that don't have a default value provided, I want to keep original type with  `| undefined`.

What I have right now works, but would it be possible to prevent type casting  `as Partial<T>`?

```
const setDefaults = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T | undefined,
  defaults: Pick<T, K>,
) => {
  return { ...defaults, ...(data as Partial<T>) }
}

type MyData = {
  id: number,
  roles: Array<string>,
}

let data: MyData | undefined

const { id, roles } = setDefaults(data, { roles: [] })

console.log(id) // number | undefined
console.log(roles) // Array<string>
```

Comment: `undefined` is *not* a `Partial<T>`. A `Partial<T>` is always an object, though it may not have any fields. That cast you're performing is a white lie to the type system, so there's not going to be any way to do it short of forcing the type checker at gunpoint to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but I was trying to figure out if there's a way to infer somehow without lying.

One idea I had was to create that partial object, but the same issue happens

`const partialData: Partial<T> = { ...data } // Type '{ [x: string]: unknown; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.`

Comment: @jcalz amazing, all I was missing was that `& Partial<T>`. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to modify your code so that we can focus on the `& Partial<T>` and not worry about the other stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `data` really is *not* `Partial<T>`; it's `T | undefined`.  It's *`defaults`* that is `Partial<T>`.  My suggested fix is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the type of `defaults` with `Partial<T>` so that the compiler understands that any properties not explicitly mentioned in the argument are of type `undefined` (instead of just `unknown`):

```
const setDefaults = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  data: T | undefined,
  defaults: Pick<T, K> & Partial<T>, // <-- here
) => {
  return { ...defaults, ...data }
}
```

This has the same `Pick<T, K> & Partial<T>` return type as before, so everything works as expected:

```
const { id, roles } = setDefaults(data, { roles: [] })  
id; // number | undefined
roles; // Array<string>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAOSlAJjAgjGKAJwBcBLAexBQG9gUVEqYSVCSARKAMzAFcANiRgoAvCgA8AFRRQAHiSggcKCgCMAVlEQkANCgDSshUpUBrKAE8K3FFIB8ACnoMUWMCTAAuOygA+KHzKPGQg2LouDFg8-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)